# Mobile site too wide, viewport tag doesn't work

Tags: css, mobile, width, viewport

There's a desktop version of the site and I'm making its mobile version by editing the same CSS files.

I hide many wide/unnecessary elements with `display: none;` and I made sure I'm using percentage widths on most elements.

On the HTML, I have the following viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

...but it doesn't help: the mobile version appears too wide on the mobile devices. The user needs to zoom in and he/she can scroll the website horizontally. Obviously, this is undesirable, I need the page to fit the width of the mobile device's screen.

Am I missing something? By the way, the framework uses Smarty, if that helps.

EDIT: SOMETIMES, the website adjusts its width to the mobile screen, but this happened just a few times and I can't figure out how or why.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing in?

Comment: I'm testing it on my android phone and an iphone. It's supposed to work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @user1020567 thats with the most problems, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

But because you do not use "media-queries"?

> > Ex: @media (max-width: 480px) {
> >     css..
> >     }

You would use media to desktop and one for phone, so you would have a specific css for each.

Comment: The client asked me to do this by checking the user agent. I cannot use responsive design, sadly.

Comment: The client hired *you* because *you* are the professional, not them.  User Agents cannot be trusted to correctly identify themselves, and the list of UA strings must be updated every time a new one comes out.  This is more work, requires more maintenance in the long run, and is less reliable than just using media queries.

Comment: Try explaining that to the client, who stressed that he doesn't want responsive design. I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the fix has nothing to do with the viewport.

The problem was caused by framesets. The framework I'm working on has a strange home page structure - index.php contains a frameset, which loads the rest of the page. Don't ask me why, I'm clueless myself.

I fixed the issue by redirecting the browser directly to the website files (avoiding the frameset whatsoever).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was using `justify-content: center`.

I resolved it by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the same css class that added `justify-content: center`;